# What would you call an item for task list?

Tags: sharepoint-online

That terminology would you call something that is under SharePoint's Task List? I don't want to call it an Item.

Comment: A task? Or am I reading you wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally these are items, because that's what we have to work with at the lowest level in SharePoint, files and items. Specifically, it is a Task, as a Tasks list would aggregate tasks. Looking at the content type in the list, you should see Task if you enable the content types in the advanced settings.